# Testing for ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let J be the ideal of a ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ generated by monomial $x$.

i) Is J a prime ideal?

ii) Is it a maximal ideal?

iii) Describe the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}/J$

Okay so for i) I said Yes, ex. Let a and b be two polynomials in $Q[x]$ then $x\mid ab \implies x\mid a  \text{ or }x\mid b $, hence it is a prime ideal (not sure if correct) But this was my thought.

ii) not sure on how to deal with this one since we're dealing with a polynomial.

iii) I would say the quotient ring is $\mathbb Q[x]/(x)$ where $(x)$ is the principal ideal geberated by $x$ (still not sure if this is correct)...

Comment: What is the ring $Q$?

Comment: rational should have been mathbb Q I guess

Comment: Then you should edit your post.

Comment: All right it should be fixed now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a *surjective* ring homomorphism
\begin{align}
\mathbb Q[x]&\longrightarrow\mathbb Q,\\p(x)&\longmapsto p(0).
\end{align}
Its kernel is precisely the ideal $(x)$, hence the *first isomorphism theorem* yields an  isomorphism
$$\mathbb Q[x]/(x)\simeq\mathbb Q,$$
which proves both the ideal $(x)$ is maximal and it is prime, and describes the quotient ring..

Comment: Thanks, I am still a little confused about how you can see that it is a surjective homomorphism?

Comment: Suppose you take for $p(x)$ a constant polynomial. What will be its image?

Comment: There will be no gradient so it's 0?

Comment: What does the gradient have to do here? This is pure algebra. Could you explain more what you mean?

Comment: I was just thinking of image in terms of a  function

Comment: No, $p(0)$ is just the constant term of the polynomial.

Comment: So if there is an isomorphism between a quotient ring and its class of numbers then we have that the ideal is a maximal and prime?

Comment: Not in general. But here, the quotient is a field, so the ideal is maximal. As as a field is also an integral domain, it also means the ideal is prime (in any ring,  maximal ideals are prime).

Comment: Okay seems like I should study the first isomorphism theorem in greater detail, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $ Q $ has zero divisors then I) is wrong as x does not divide constant polynomials but it will divide their product if it happens to be $0 $.

Comment: Usually $\mathbb{Q}$ denotes the field of rational numbers.

Comment: It was written $ Q $ when I wrote this, and it said "a ring" suggesting it could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There is a much simpler description of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x)$ than the one you have given. Figure out what ring that is isomorphic to. Once you do that, the answers to (i) and (ii) should follow from the fact that an ideal is prime (maximal) if and only if the quotient ring is a domain (field).